# Can I add a bean validation annotation with group?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I want to build a `NotNull` check that only work on `Create` group, so I can write like this

```
@Data
public static class TestDto {

    @NotNullOnCreate
    // @NotNull(groups = Create.class) // instead of this
    private String id;
}
```

I create the `NotNullOnCreate` like this

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Repeatable(NotNullOnCreate.List.class)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@NotNull(groups = Create.class)
@interface NotNullOnCreate {

    String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {

        NotNullOnCreate[] value();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, because composing constraint annotation's (see [ConstraintDescriptorImpl#createComposingConstraintDescriptor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/76338de7feabcca0641efce22ec7786e5da022b7/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/metadata/descriptor/ConstraintDescriptorImpl.java#L762)) group will be set to host annotation's group('Default').

I also tried this `Class<?>[] groups() default {Create.class};`, but this is not allowed, the default group must empty.

How can I achieve this ? I don't want to write the group everywhere.

**EDIT**

- Create [HV-1355](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HV/issues/HV-1355) Constraint annotation with explicit groups
- Wrote a workable demo project [hv-annotation-with-group](https://github.com/wenerme/hv-annotation-with-group)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment. If you like, open an issue in the Hibernate Validator [issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV) and we can explore this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I've created HV-1355